# GradientMagnitudeImageFilter in ITK

Tags: itk

What does [`GradientMagnitudeImageFilter`](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/EdgesAndGradients/GradientMagnitudeImageFilter) do in ITK (i.e. what is the formulation)?
Is it just a sobel filter? is the equivalent in skimage [`filters.sobel`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.html#skimage.filters.sobel)? The ITK documentation is somewhat sparse on how it works.

Answer (score 0):

It is not just a Sobel filter, which also [exists](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1SobelEdgeDetectionImageFilter.html) in ITK. Unlike Sobel, it takes spacing into account. ITK has many more [edge related](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples#Image_Edges.2C_Gradients.2C_and_Derivatives) filters.

Comment: What do you mean it takes spacing into account?

Comment: Take a look at the code here: https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/master/Modules/Filtering/ImageGradient/include/itkGradientMagnitudeImageFilter.hxx

Comment: In the case with isotropic pixels, it seems to boil down to the difference between `DerivativeOperator` and `SobelOperator`. What is the difference between those?